# Monitoring LDAP traffic for direct DN queries

Tags: active-directory, ldap-query

I'm an MS Active Directory admin.  I have a new project that entails moving some AD OUs around.  Some of these OUs have been in place for many years.  I'm concerned if I move these OUs, it might break services that utilize a direct LDAP DN query.

For example, if I've got a OU at OU=Test_OU,dc=domain,dc=local and I move it I'm concerned there will be applications out there that have OU=Test_OU,dc=domain,dc=local explicitly in their configuration.  The moment I move this OU thus changing the LDAP DN the service will break.

I'm currently to the point to where I've setup Wireshark on my DC and am applying a capture filter for TCP/389.  I've perused through the traffic and can see that I think I should be looking for the SearchRequest attribute which appears to contain the DN.  Based on these packets, I'll then do a search to find out if the OU I'm looking to move has been explicitly accessed via the current LDAP DN and plan accordingly.

I hesitate to do this because I'm unfamiliar with the LDAP protocol itself.  Is finding all incoming LDAP SearchRequest packets the best route to go there or do I need to look for other LDAP traffic?

Comment: *Don't* do it. Use aliases.

Comment: Can you clarify?  How am I supposed to find existing services already configured?

Comment: When I say don't I mean don't. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using object auditing for this? Kinda a weird use case but if tuned correctly might lead you down the right path.

Answer (score -1):

You aren't supposed to 'find existing services already configured'. You aren't supposed to make *any* changes to your DIT that would break existing applications.

The DIT shouldn't attempt to be a mirror of your organization's structure, because organisation structures are a lot cheaper to change than DIT's. If by some mischance you have built or inherited a DIT that does mirror it, you are stuck with it, but you should leave it strictly alone, and use aliases rather than internal reorganisations to provide the new structure that you need now.